# React simple Higher Order Component

Tags: reactjs, react-props, react-functional-component, higher-order-components

My purpose is to make a simple *Higher Order Component* where I have a reusable Section component and where I maybe define some css classes and the `<section>` tag:

```
import React from 'react'

function SectionWrapper(props) {
  return <section>{props.children}</section>
}

export default SectionWrapper
```

Now in my Parent component I can wrap my child-section components like this:

```
<SectionWrapper>
  <SectionTitle />
</SectionWrapper>

<SectionWrapper>
  <List />
</SectionWrapper>
```

Is there a cleaner way to achieve this? E.g. how do I pass the child-component as a prop?

Comment: You could convert this to a HOC, but with such a simple example that doesn't inject any new props or behavior into what it wraps I don't much see the point of a wrapper being a HOC.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you could do -

```
const withSection = (Component) => (props) =>
 <section><Component {...props}/></section>

const EnhancedSectionTitle = withSection(SectionTitle)
```

Then use it like

```
<EnhancedSectionTitle />
```

Rename `EnhancedSectionTitle` to whatever makes sense in your app

Answer (score 0):

You could convert the section wrapper to a Higher Order Component as such:

```
const withSection = Component => props => (
  <section>
    <Component {...props} />
  </section>
);
```

Ensure you return a valid react component that allows props to be passed through to the underlying component being wrapped.

Usage:

```
const ComponentWithSection = withSection(MyComponent);

...

<ComponentWithSection myProp={myAwesomeProp} />
```